# An example of a local ring which is not CM and a MCM module over it

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I am looking for an example of a commutative noetherian local ring $(A,m)$,
and a maximal Cohen-Macaulay module $M$ over $A$ (in particular $M$ is finitely generated over $A$), such that for some $p \in Spec(A)$, we have that $M_p = 0$,
and $A_p$ is also not a Cohen-Macaulay ring. Do there exist such examples?

Comment: Let $A$ be the local ring of a union of two $2$-planes intersecting in one point $x$ in a $4$-dimensional ambient space.  Let $M$ be the local ring of one of the two irreducible components.  Let $p$ be a prime ideal of a curve in the other component that contains $x$.  If you really want $A$ to be not Cohen-Macaulay at $p$, then just add some embedded structure to $A$ along $p$.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a concrete example, inspired by Jason Starr's comment but of smaller dimension.

Let $A=k[x,y,z]_{(x,y,z)} / (x^2z, xyz)$.  Let $p=(x,y)A$.  Let $M=A/zA$, thought of as a cyclic $A$-module.  Then $M \cong k[x,y]_{(x,y)}$ is a maximal Cohen-Macaulay module over $A$, since $\dim A = \operatorname{depth} M = 2$.   We have that $p$ is prime because $A/p \cong k[z]_{(z)}$. We have that $M_p = 0$ because $z \notin p$, so $z$ acts like a unit on $A_p$-modules but kills $M$.  Finally, $A_p \cong k(z)[x,y]_{(x,y)} / (x^2, xy)$ has dimension 1 and depth 0.